# Starting Tornado Web

Tags: python, ubuntu, tornado

I'm quite new to using Tornado Web as a web server, and am having a little difficulty keeping it running. I normally use Django and Nginx, and am used to start/stop/restarting the server. However with Tornado I'm having trouble telling it to "run" without directly executing my main python file for the site, ie "python ~/path/to/server.py".

I'm sure I'm getting this completely wrong - is there a way of 'bootstrapping' my script so that when Nginx starts, Tornado starts?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a way to have nginx spawn your tornado instance.

Typically you would use an external framework like [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or a system init script to run the tornado process.

Comment: Additionally an init script is a SysV standard and generally expected by others as a standard mechanism to start and stop your service. 

Alternatives would be upstart or the Solaris equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do it is using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) as it is also written in python

Comment: A language choice doesn't make something better on it's own; daemontools is rock solid. I was also only suggesting something 'like' daemontools, clearly there is a long list of options (including supervisord).

Comment: It's better for his needs despite that it might not be better than daemontools.

Comment: I'm partial to an init (or upstart, inittab, whatever) script to start it and Monit to check it's "health" and restart as needed. Two birds with one stone.